# Logstash - Parsing the JSON

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, filebeat

I have a JSON log that comes to Logstash.
It looks like this:

> ```
>  [{"orderNumber":"xxxxxxxx","externalOrderNumber":"07efc4c7d3113453427f7fe525e22a61e","operation":{"name":"CAPTURE","amount":990,"status":"PENDING","createdAt":"2011-05-11T04:58:21.187Z","updatedAt":{}}}]
>  [{"paymentMethod":"Card","transactionId":"331d83fd-2456-48320-842a-f4122aa311e1","orderStatus":"SUCCESS","statuses":[{"amount":990,"operation":"CAPTURE","status":"SUCCESS","createdAt":"2012-05-11T04:58:26.252Z"},{"amount":990,"operation":"CAPTURE","status":"PENDING","createdAt":"2012-05-11T04:58:26.224Z"},{"amount":990,"operation":"AUTHORISE","status":"SUCCESS","createdAt":"2012-05-11T04:58:26.198Z"},{"amount":990,"operation":"AUTHORISE","status":"PENDING","createdAt":"2012-05-11T04:58:16.304Z"}]}]
> ```

Which is basically [{SOMEJSON}][{MOREJSON}]

I was thinking to do a pattern where I grab the first "[" then I do %{GREEDYDATA:firstjson} until the ]. The simply repeat the procedure.

I was not successfull in making this happen. I am stuck at the start with the '['

I have tried this Logstash:

```
grok {
       match => { "message" => "\[%{GREEDYDATA:firstjson}\]%{SPACE} \[%{GREEDYDATA:second}\]"}
    }
```

But it only grabs the first JSON.

Comment: Just split it by endline character.

Comment: It would be best to use the [JSON filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-json.html) for this.

Comment: Yes, I am already using it.

Comment: Looks like a [multiline event](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/5.4/multiline.html), am I right?

Comment: Yes. You are right :). Multiline coming from Filebeat.

Comment: are you in different line ? what you want line1 = firstjson line = second?